# set uploaded video length limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

After setup the carrier-wave video, i noticed that after upload the video the gem
has a `after_transcode: :set_success` callback.
that seems possible to configure.

I would like to know if by carrierwave is possible to set the video lenght after or before the transcoding by carrierwave.

Because in the docs seems that don't have mention to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the gem to do this kind of work
https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use another library. See https://github.com/zencoder/rvideo

With this you'll be able to check the duration on the file in your create action, before you validate the save. If the duration is above the threshold, return an error.

Comment: Paul thank for your answer, i did find gem ‘streamio-ffmpeg’
seems in active development. did you know about this gem?